# TYPO3 sets always some extension database values to 1

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I am usung TYPO3 V11.5.3 and figured out, that some pages not working anymore. The reason was, that in the database of the extension, in some entries the delete flag have been set.
If I set this values back to 0 with phpmyadmin, the next day these values are again set to 1 and the web pages are not working.
What's going on there?
How can I avoid it, that TYPO3 sets again these values?

**Edit**

Rudi, this extension has worked for about 1 year without any problem.

The extension has 3 databases, Album, Discs and Tracks. A album has one or more discs and a number of tracks. The extion is collecting this information (BE) and displays it (FE).

Can it be, that TYPO3 is automatically setting back the changes I have made with phpmyadmin?

** EDIT **

I tried several things, but they didn't solved theproblem!
Finally, I deleted the effected tables and but them new. These seems to solve the problem.

Comment: TYPO3 will not just delete records by itself. Something has to cause it. Can you tell us some more about the functionality of the extension?

Comment: A good place to take a look into is the scheduler module. There are some regularly executed tasks running which may cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out was the problem was.

I generated my extension via extension_builder. And extension-builder created a list view for the frontend, which I didn't use, but also not deleted. This list view was found by GOOGLE and executed the delete function of this list view!